# How to export a variable (its a list actually) to other .js file in a function inside class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to export a variable or a list which is modified inside a function inside the class to other .js file?

```
renderBoxContent = () => {

  let total = 0;
  let Total = 0;
  let itemList = [];
  let  data = [];

  this.state.availableItems.map((items)=> {

      if(items.purchase > 0){
       Total += items.price*items.purchase;
       total = items.price*items.purchase;
       console.log(items.purchase);
       console.log(total);

          data.push(
          {
            key: items.name,
            name: items.name,
            // src: items.image,
            singlePrice: items.price.toFixed(2),
            purchase: items.purchase,
            totalItemPrice: total.toFixed(2),
          }
        )
      }
  })


  //how to export 'data' to other .js file?

  itemList.push(  <Table defaultExpandAllRows={false} locale={{emptyText: 'Empty Cart'}} style={{background: '#ffffff'}} pagination={false} columns={column} dataSource={data} size="small" />)
  itemList.push( <h3 style={{paddingLeft:15,paddingTop:20}}>    Total     {Total.toFixed(2)}</h3>)
  return itemList;
 }
```

Should be able to access and import the 'data' list variable in other .js file

Comment: create a function in exporting class, which returns the list you want to export 

import that class in file where you need that function

and call the functions which returns the list

Comment: How to call the specific function in the imported calss

Comment: if function you are exporting is part of another react component you are doing it wrong , but if it is just a helper file which have functions you want then you can import className from 'PATH_TO_FILE';
then 
className.function();

Answer (score 1):

**What about using [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)?**

First create and export your context

```
export const DataContext = React.createContext();
```

Wrap your components in a provider component and give it your data

```
<DataContext.Provider value={data}>
```

And consume it like this in your other component

```
import DataContext from '...' // add your path
const data = useContext(DataContext)
```

If your components are either parents or grand parents of each other, i recommend you [pass the value as props between components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are working with react, so simply put you should look into [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) or [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), instead of creating custom functions to import and export data from one file to an other.
both of above are used to create a global state which can be accessed in any file of your project.

it will be little bit difficult to understand them at first, but once you get to know how to use them (one of them) it will make global state management very easy for you.